# How can we enable Active directory authorization in report portal?

Tags: reportportal

I have configured below details for AD authorization for Report portal. I followed https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/ for configuration details. Refer below pic.

[image]

But I am not able to enable it. I can not see the switch button for AD like GitHub authorization.
[image]

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

It's already enabled, based on the screen. If it is configured incorrectly, login UI will say that credentials are invalid.
In order to get more details, you can grab logs of `service-authorization` component